# SystemVerilog hierarchical references through virtual interface

Tags: system-verilog

When using interfaces to slice another interface (see Brad's blog post: [bradpierce.wordpress.com/2014/07/06/](https://bradpierce.wordpress.com/2014/07/06/)), I run into a problem when using the sliced interface as virtual.
Adding this line into Brad's code:

```
virtual sliceIfc#(0) vif;
```

I then get a bunch of warnings like this:

> xmelab: *W,CUVIHR (./tb.sv,15|17): This virtual interface declaration
> type 'sliceIfc' makes hierarchical reference to 'allInst.Requests[I]'.

Is the LRM disallowing a virtual interface which makes hierarchical references to interfaces contained within the virtual interface? If so, is there a better suggestion for slicing interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the LRM does say the following (in 25.9):

```
Although an interface may contain hierarchical references to objects outside its body or ports that reference other interfaces, it shall be illegal to use an interface containing those references in the declaration of a virtual interface.
```

This is a little vague, and, to my knowledge, different tools give different behaviors. xmelab only gives a warning in this case, so elaboration should finish correctly, and the behavior of the elaborated design should not be affected.

Comment: I'm worried about how this will be handled in the future. Any insight into that?

Comment: Presumably, the LRM is trying to prevent cyclical dependencies (my interface references another interface, which references the first interface) -- I doubt any eda vendor would error out/fail to elaborate for cases beside that, except if at some point in the future the LRM actually becomes clearer and significantly more restrictive.